# Character limit isn't working on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, frontend

I've used the below script to limit characters with the resize of window, it works as I wanted it on desktop web, but when I open the page on iPad, the characters aren't limiting or changing. What could be the done to fix this? any help would be appreciated.

```
/*limit characters in featured text column */
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1270) {
            $(".i-trim-header").addClass('i-text-trim');
            $(".i-trim-header").each(function(i){
                len=$(this).text().length;
                if(len>25) {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,25)+'...');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.i-trim-header').removeClass('i-text-trim');
            $(".i-trim-header").each(function(i){
                $(this).text($(this).data('.i-trim-header-o'));
            });
        }
    }
    $(".i-trim-header").each(function(){
        $(this).data({originalTxt: $(this).text()});
      });
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

/* default character limit in text column */
// <![CDATA[
$(function(){
    $(".i-trim-header-o").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
        if(len>55) {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,55)+'...');
        }
    });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->Safari->Advanced->JavaScript and make sure it's turned on although most javascript codes don't work on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm using chrome on ipad. and Javascript is on.

Comment: and javascript is enabled on safari too, but its not working.

Comment: Add `alert($(window).width());` and check if the given width is lower than 1270.

Comment: Also note that if you use the ipad in landscape mode it takes the height as width. My iPad's width is 980 and height is 1154 (1160 on chrome)... So that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: I checked and the width is 786 on portrait and 1024 on landscape on both chrome and safari on ipad. But its still now working. :(